# Citeron C4 Picasso I 1.6 THP Turbo Diverter Valve

Tags: turbocharger, citroen

Having P2262 and P2099 codes, and when I bench the diverter valve with 12v battery, the valve will energize and retract which seems normal.

But when it is mounted to the turbo.
1. While looking for the ground wire.  I found both wires are grounded to the chassis, but not to battery negative terminal
2. With engine running.  one of the wire is producing 13v+ with chassis ground but valve is not energized. 
3. inserting the multi-meter positive probes to either connector, and negative to battery.  revving the engine will not bring up enough voltage to energize the valve. only shows 0.02v +-.

is there a electrical short somewhere?  or I am doing the whole test wrong?

Comment: How did you decide the battery negative is not connected to the chassis?

Comment: The battery negative is connected to the chassis.  I get continuity when I probe battery negative to chassis..  But what is baffling me is.  when I probe the wires to the DV.  I get continuity to chassis on both wires.  But not when I probe DV wires to battery negative terminal.

Comment: Are you reversing the meter probes?

Comment: I actually did both ways, same results. Going bonkers already LOL!!