# Citeron Turbo Wastegate Actuator Setup

Tags: turbocharger, citroen, turbo-lag

Hoping someone here will have the turbo wastagate actuator setting/specification.  for the Citroen C4 Picasso I 1.6 thp EP6/AL4

I got the car used, about 2 years ago, and it is not lacking any power, but the engine have always been surging when stop and in drive mode.  But in recent weeks, it got worse, starting with failing camshaft position sensor, ignition coil and VVT oil control solenoid, and after replacing all these parts, except for the VVT solenoid which I clean, and all codes did not re-appear, but the car have lost turbo boost.  with P2099 and P2262.

Searching the web.  it seems that my wastegate actuator is out of spec, as it was position about 10mm shorter then the suggested 151.5mm (151,5mm is base on result I got from peugeot forum).

With the 151.5mm information.  I remove the actuator arm from the lever.  Manually position the wastegate to fully shut close position.  Apply vacuum with a hand pump and the actuator arm moved about 10mm with 14in/hg vacuum applied, and anymore vacuum it will not move further, and leaving it in position.  re-install the wastegate lever, and measured the actuator rod length, and true enough, it was about 151.xx +-2mm (As suggested in my web search).  I leave it in this position as at now.

The adjustment seems to have solved the engine surging, and car is idling nicely now.  But still no boost with P2262 most of the time, and P2099 when I push the throttle beyond 4k rpm. which is a totally different issue.  But I have to at least get the correct wastegate setting in place for now before moving on to solve the other issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it really rev that high ?

Comment: What about this : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/67561/10976

Comment: Sorry.  4K rpm..  LOL!!!